# Update mongoose node js without defined schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I’m developing an app in NodeJS with mongoose for mongodb.

For some reasons, I don't define the schema, I just insert into the mongo the whole object that came from another function.

The problem is, when I try to update one object, I can't update one of the fields that is not defined in the schema. I just can update one field that is defined.

For example

```
var caseSchema = new mongo.Schema({
    dhists : String,
    dVisible : {'type':'number', default:1}
});
```

And, to create the object

```
var DCase = new dcase(data, false);
```

And then I use the other fields

```
DCase.dhists = JSON.stringify(hists);
```

This, in my mongodb has like 20 fields (18 from my source and 2 from my defined schema).

When I try to update one of the 18 fields, it doesn't update. When I try to update one of the other 2 fields (that are defined in the schema) it works.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to make a patchy system even more patchy. Better to get it right. If this wasn't done the first place, now is the time to do it. Don't build up technical debts - the take their toll sooner or later. So create a ctor which takes the object from the other function and initializes the fields of a model. As a matter of fact, fields which aren't mapped with Mongoose can't be persisted with mongoose. However, you can persist them manually.

Comment: Review the mongoose docs strict option: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.0.x/docs/guide.html#strict

Comment: @Yousef is right. You need to set the strict option to false.